# AngularJS event method called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a history of user typed messages from one text area into the other text area.
But as soon as a character is typed in first text area, it gets copied into second text area multiple times. Looks as if my event and hence the Angular Controller method is being invoked multiple times.

Can somebody pls have a look at this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w4g417bt/

Code:

```
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div data-ng-app='myNoteTakingApp1'
        data-ng-controller="myNoteTakingController1">
        <div style="float: left">

            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" data-ng-model="message"></textarea>
            <br> Characters Left: {{ left() }}

        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 25em">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" data-ng-model="messageHistory"
                data-ng-disabled='true'></textarea>
            <br> Characters Left: {{ leftHistory() }}
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: 21em">
            <button data-ng-click="clear();">Clear</Button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myNoteTakingApp1', []);

        app.controller('myNoteTakingController1', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "";
            $scope.messageHistory = "";
            $scope.left = function() {
                return 100 - $scope.message.length;
            }
            $scope.leftHistory = function() {
                $scope.messageHistory += $scope.message;
                return 500 - $scope.messageHistory.length;
            }
            $scope.clear = function() {
                $scope.message = "";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This is because, everytime digest loop is running, left() and leftHistory() is being called. You should call those method on ng-change, and show the character left via a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should it not be `$scope.messageHistory = $scope.message;` instead of `+=` as you are appending whole message again and again?

or simply use same model for both?

```
$scope.leftHistory = function() {
                $scope.messageHistory = $scope.message;
                return 500 - $scope.messageHistory.length;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you had below mistakes

Change lefsthistory code to this

```
    $scope.leftHistory = function() {
        $scope.messageHistory = $scope.message;
        return 500 - $scope.messageHistory.length;
   }
```

You were trying $scope.messageHistory += $scope.message;
instead put $scope.messageHistory = $scope.message;

look on this jsfiddle
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4g417bt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (in console):

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Why?:

1. The first digest cycle after pressing the `a` on keyboard changes the `message` variable on the `$scope`.
2. The digest cycle goes further and checks if any of the watchers (i.e. `{{ }}`) are changed. -> Invokes left() & leftHistroy()
3. The `leftHistory` function changes `$scope.messageHistory`
4. The digest cycle goes further and sees that messageHistory has changed -> invoke watchers
5. Endless loop - exit after 10 cycles